# Не могу подключиться к базе postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring

Проект рабочий, на Java и крутиться на сервере.
Пытаюсь подключиться к базе postgresql и получаю такую ошибку:

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Вот настройки из файла application.yaml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: @spring.profiles.active@
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always
    platform: convert
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mark_convert
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mark_convert
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog.xml
```

Вот файл Docker-compose

```
  postgres-converter:
    container_name: postgres-converter
    image: postgres:13.2-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=converter
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_converter_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Вот настройки подключения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если бы кто-то поменял пароль в БД, тогда и Java приложение не смогло бы работать с этой БД?
Меня так же смущает строки

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mark_convert
```

и

```
- POSTGRES_DB=converter
```

Какое все-таки имя у БД.
Я пробовал установить соединение и так и так. Таже самая ошибка.
Разработчик данного проекта пропал, спросить не у кого.

Приведу еще файл для liquibase, но меня он еще больше запутал, там совсем другие названия указаны.

```html
    <createTable  tableName="converter_history" schemaName="history">
        <column  name="id"  type="BIGINT"  autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints  primaryKey="true"  nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column  name="type"  type="varchar(20)"/>
        <column  name="pic_number"  type="varchar(4)"/>
        <column  name="part_number_oem"  type="varchar(50)"/>
        <column name="date_added" type="timestamp" defaultValueComputed="current_timestamp">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="result" type="varchar(50)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
```

Comment: настройки auth нет.

Comment: А можно подробней. Где нет. Можете в виде ответа, а я зачту его как правильный.

Comment: Извините, а не могли бы Вы уточнить еще воот что: в настройках сооединения (на картинке) у вас хост 1.1.1.1, а в настройках application.yaml -localhost. Это меня немноого смущает, я правильно понимаю, что там настроен еще и reverse proxy на других вкладках?

Comment: Дело в том что БД крутится на сервере, в соединении я указываю реальный ip-адрес сервера. 1.1.1.1 - я указал, чтобы не светить реальный ip. В приложении указан localhost - это я так понимаю потому что они крутятся на одном сервере и приложение и БД. Или у меня тоже только вариант подключаться только зайдя на сервер

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы назвали свою бд `converter`

```
      - POSTGRES_DB=converter
```

2. Вы пытаетесь подлючиться к БД `mark_convert`

```
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mark_convert
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mark_convert
```

При этом из GUI приложения вы подключаетесь к `converter`.
Определитесь уже :)

Comment: Да дело в том, что не я назвал. Я пытаюсь разобраться как оно работает. Я тоже не понимаю зачем такая путаница, но дело в том, что она работает. И вот я пытаюсь понять как это все работает.